# GET and POST for same route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a `get` and `post` method for the same route in Rails so I created these two.

```
group_add GET    /groups/:group_id/add(.:format)        usergroups#new
          POST   /groups/:group_id/add(.:format)        usergroups#new
```

This is in my `Routes.rb` file

```
resources :groups do
    get 'add', to: 'usergroups#new', controller: 'usergroups'
    post 'add', to: 'usergroups#new', controller: 'usergroups'
end
```

I am able to navigate to that page with the `group_add` path which is the `GET` request however when I am clicking submit on this form (should be the post request) nothing is happening.

It is re-directing back to the form which is suppose to happen if the form does not save in the create method. The parameters are being passed in the server logs however the user is not being added to the group. Any ideas why this wouldn't be posting?

```
<%= form_for @usergroup, url: group_add_path do |form| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :user_id %>
        <%= form.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:email), :id, :email, {}, { :id => 'user_select', placeholder: 'Test' } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :group_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select :group_id, Group.all, :id, :group_name, {}, { :id => 'group_select', placeholder: 'Test' } %>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit 'Add user', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does the log say? Are there any errors shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code you have directed both the `get` and the `post` to `usergroups#new`, but you should send the `post` to `usergroups#create`.

Comment: There might be different use cases for both methods in same action.

Comment: OP has indicated that he expects the form submission to redirect back to itself if it is not saved in the create method. . . so he should make the `post` go to the `#create` method.